# Drawing map in QGIS from QGIS plugin

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, wms, getmap

I am writing a Python plugin for QGIS. In my plugin, I can fetch data by a WMS GetMap request but I can't draw the map in QGIS from the response I got from my GetMap call.

Suppose I have a variable like below:

```
    data = requests.get(http://mysite.com/wms?request=GetMap.....)
```

Now I want to draw this **data** in QGIS.  How can I do this?

Comment: Perhaps this post might help: [Load WMS with PyQGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/183485/load-wms-with-pyqgis)