# Loading WMS layer to QGIS using Python

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, wms, qgis-2

I know that there are already many questions regarding this matter. In fact, I have already seen the following questions:

- [How to load a WMS layer using PyQGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/120823)
- [Adding a WMS layer in QGIS using python](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/199382)
- [Load WMS with PyQGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/183485)
- [WMS layer in a QGIS 2.4 stand alone Python script](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/116238)
- [How to open a specific WMS layer in QGIS with a single URL?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/277421)

I am working on making a plugin for QGIS 2.18 using python 2.7 on Windows. Here is my code:

```
wms_url="http://localhost/MapServer/mapserv.exe?map=c:/inetpub/wwwroot/data//Mapfile.map&request=GetMap&service=WMS&version=1.3.0&layers=Region_Map&width=480.000&height=480.000&format=image/png&bbox=8.473957,77.262417,8.519412,77.307871&crs=EPSG:4326&styles="

wms_url = wms_url + "&styles="
print(wms_url)
# setting prefix path of qgis
# TODO: get this path dynamically
qgis_prefix = "C:\\OSGeo4W64\\apps\\qgis-ltr"
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath(qgis_prefix, True)
QgsApplication.initQgis()

#adding the WMS Layer
rlayer = QgsRasterLayer(wms_url, 'default map', 'wms, True)
print(rlayer.isValid())
if(rlayer.isValid):
    QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(rlayer)
else:
    print(rlayer.error().message())
```

Once this code is executed, the following messages are seen:

CONSOLE:

> False
>
> **Raster layer:** Provider is not valid (provider: wms, URI:
>   http://localhost/MapServer/mapserv.exe?map=Mapfile.map&request=GetMap&service=WMS&version=1.3.0&layers=Layer&width=480.000&height=480.000&format=image/png&bbox=8.473957,77.262417,8.519412,77.307871&crs=EPSG:4326&styles=

(The second line contains a u' and followed by a p and b tad at the start of the statement in the console; I am unable to show it exactly here)

Logs:
[image: QGIS Log Error]

(It says `Download of capabilities failed: Protocol "" is unknown`)

Based on the answers I read, I have also tried the following:

1. Changing the url to `http://localhost/MapServer/mapserv.exe?map=Mapfile.map&layers=Layer&styles=&format=image/png&crs=EPSG:4326`
2. Clearing the QGIS cache
3. Adding the prefix path to `QgsApplication` (evident from the code).

I should also add that this url works perfectly when run on web browser or if the url `http://localhost/MapServer/mapserv.exe?map=Mapfile.map` is added to "Add WMS/WMTS Layer" (GUI option). Also, if I remove the `'wms'` in the above code, then an image is added, although it does not get loaded to the correct dimensions.

Is there something else that I am missing?

*Some Additional Info*

From the following link [pyQGIS Developer Cookbook](https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/loadlayer.html#raster-layers)

> Alternatively you can load a raster layer from WMS server. However
>   currently it’s not possible to access GetCapabilities response from
>   API — you have to know what layers you want:

```
urlWithParams = 'url=http://irs.gis-lab.info/? 
layers=landsat&styles=&format=image/jpeg&crs=EPSG:4326'
rlayer = QgsRasterLayer(urlWithParams, 'some layer name', 'wms')
if not rlayer.isValid():
  print "Layer failed to load!"
```

This suggests that the first parameter should be the full URL to the WMS request with the provider being `'wms'` as visible in the code above.

Comment: Note from the WMS specification the  & is used at the end of the parameter and the equals sign can be omitted, so a default style would be `styles&` not `&styles=`

Comment: Width and height should be integers not decimals, this might also cause you problems so `width=480&height=480& not `width=480.000&height=480.000&`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not really know the reason, but changing the entered URL to the following format works:

```
wms_url = "url=http://localhost/MapServer/mapserv.exe?map=Mapfile.map&layers=layers&styles=&format=image/png&crs=EPSG:4326
```

It was basically to add a `url=` before the entered URL and keeping the entered request to contain only the `map`, `layers`, `styles`, `format` and `crs` parameters. Also, it seems to work even without the `QgsApplication` part of the code for me.